# Parallelization of a simple function using multiprocessing with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Can someone help me create a multiprocessing version of the **makeSubsets** function? It basically calculates an index using the **degree** function and adds the element index (referring to the input set) to the subsets vector at the position calculated by the **degree** function.

My functional code, without multiprocessing.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.spatial import distance
import math

class Testing(object):
    
    def __init__(self, inputSet, divisor):
        self.set = inputSet
        self.divisor = divisor
        
    def __build__(self):

        self.reference = self.__reference__()
        self.num_subsets = ((len(self.set)-1) // self.divisor)
        self.subsets = [[] for i in range(self.num_subsets)]
        
        self.__makeSubsets__()
       
    def __degree__(self, xk, c1, c2):
        
        d_xk_c1 = distance.euclidean(xk, c1)
        d_xk_c2 = distance.euclidean(xk, c2)

            
        return d_xk_c1/(d_xk_c1 + d_xk_c2)
  
    def __makeSubsets__(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(len(self.set)):
            index = int(self.__degree__(self.set[i], self.reference[0], self.reference[1]) * self.num_subsets)
            self.subsets[index].append(i)
        print("MAKE SUBSETS --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - total_time))
        
    def __reference__(self):
        dimension = len(self.set[0])
        size = len(self.set)

        #reference[0] = min of set iset; reference[1] = max of set iset
        reference = [[], []]

        for i in range(dimension):
            reference[0].append(math.inf)
            reference[1].append(-math.inf)

        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(dimension):
                if self.set[i][j] < reference[0][j]:
                    reference[0][j] = self.set[i][j]

                if self.set[i][j] > reference[1][j]:
                    reference[1][j] = self.set[i][j]
        return reference

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    total_time = time.time()    
    N = 10000
    Set = np.random.random((N,2))

    anObjetct = Testing(inputSet = Set.tolist(), divisor = 1000)

    anObjetct .__build__()
    print("TOTAL --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - total_time))
```

**EXAMPLE INPUT**

10 vectors of two positions (as points in two-dimensional space)

```
N = 10
Set = np.random.random((N,2))
```

**OUTPUT**

Subsets containing input set slices. The values in the subsets correspond to the indexes of the elements in the input vector.

```
>>> objeto.subsets
[[0, 2, 9], [5, 7], [1, 3, 6, 8], [4]]
Execution time: 0.009 seconds
```

**-----**

I tried to create a version with multiprocessing, but it does not present the correct result, nor does it produce any results. Furthermore, the processing time is totally inconsistent.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.spatial import distance
import math

class Testing(object):
    
    def __init__(self, inputSet, divisor):
        self.set = inputSet
        self.divisor = divisor
        
    def __build__(self):

        self.reference = self.__reference__()
        self.num_subsets = ((len(self.set)-1) // self.divisor)
        self.subsets = [[] for i in range(self.num_subsets)]

        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(self.__makeParallel__,self.set)
        
        #self.__makeSubsets__()
       
    def __degree__(self, xk, c1, c2):
        
        d_xk_c1 = distance.euclidean(xk, c1)
        d_xk_c2 = distance.euclidean(xk, c2)

            
        return d_xk_c1/(d_xk_c1 + d_xk_c2)

    def __makeParallel__(self, i):
        index = math.floor(self.__degree__(i, self.reference[0], self.reference[1]) * self.num_subsets)
        self.subsets[index].append(self.set.index(i))
  
    def __makeSubsets__(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(len(self.set)):
            index = int(self.__degree__(self.set[i], self.reference[0], self.reference[1]) * self.num_subsets)
            self.subsets[index].append(i)
        print("MAKE SUBSETS --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - total_time))
        
    def __reference__(self):
        dimension = len(self.set[0])
        size = len(self.set)

        #reference[0] = min of set iset; reference[1] = max of set iset
        reference = [[], []]

        for i in range(dimension):
            reference[0].append(math.inf)
            reference[1].append(-math.inf)

        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(dimension):
                if self.set[i][j] < reference[0][j]:
                    reference[0][j] = self.set[i][j]

                if self.set[i][j] > reference[1][j]:
                    reference[1][j] = self.set[i][j]
        return reference

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    total_time = time.time()    
    N = 10000
    Set = np.random.random((N,2))

    anObjetct = Testing(inputSet = Set.tolist(), divisor = 1000)

    anObjetct .__build__()
    print("TOTAL --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - total_time))
```

**EXAMPLE INPUT**

10 vectors of two positions (as points in two-dimensional space)

```
N = 10
Set = np.random.random((N,2))
```

**OUTPUT**

Totally inconsistent result.

```
>>> objeto.subsets
[[], [], [], []]
Execution time: 0.5 seconds
```

**I just need a multiprocessing version of the **makeSubsets** function.**
pls, help!
thanks

Comment: In multiprocessing you generally need to pass stuff into the processes and collect output. You then stitch together the result. I don't think your various subprocesses will be using the same instance of the class Testing.

Comment: @forgetso do you have any suggestions on how i could implement multiprocessing or multithreading for the __makeSubsets__ function?

Comment: Yes, I've added a solution that will work with your existing class. However, I would recommend instead doing this as a "bag of functions". The class is overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The class is overkill for this problem, in my opinion, but if you want to keep it you could instantiate one of the classes in each sub processes as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.spatial import distance
import math

class Testing(object):
    
    def __init__(self, inputSet, divisor):
        self.set = inputSet
        self.divisor = divisor
        
    def __build__(self):

        self.reference = self.__reference__()
        self.num_subsets = ((len(self.set)-1) // self.divisor)
        self.subsets = [[] for i in range(self.num_subsets)]
        self.__makeSubsets__()
       
    def __degree__(self, xk, c1, c2):
        
        d_xk_c1 = distance.euclidean(xk, c1)
        d_xk_c2 = distance.euclidean(xk, c2)
        return d_xk_c1/(d_xk_c1 + d_xk_c2)

  
    def __makeSubsets__(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(len(self.set)):
            index = int(self.__degree__(self.set[i], self.reference[0], self.reference[1]) * self.num_subsets)
            self.subsets[index].append(i)
        
    def __reference__(self):
        dimension = len(self.set[0])
        size = len(self.set)

        #reference[0] = min of set iset; reference[1] = max of set iset
        reference = [[], []]

        for i in range(dimension):
            reference[0].append(math.inf)
            reference[1].append(-math.inf)

        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(dimension):
                if self.set[i][j] < reference[0][j]:
                    reference[0][j] = self.set[i][j]

                if self.set[i][j] > reference[1][j]:
                    reference[1][j] = self.set[i][j]
        return reference


import multiprocessing
# split a list into evenly sized chunks
def chunks(lst, n):
    if n < 1:
        n = 1
    result = [x for x in np.array_split(lst, n) if len(x)]
    return result

# this is the function that we actually run in parallel
# each instance has its own version of Testing class
def get_subsets(chnk):
    anObjetct = Testing(inputSet = chnk.tolist(), divisor = 1000)
    anObjetct .__build__()
    return anObjetct.subsets


# this code breaks the random data into 4 chunks and then passes these chunks to
# the multiprocessing job pool.
N = 10000
data = np.random.random((N,2))
chnks = chunks(data, 4)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
result_list = pool.map(get_subsets, chnks)

# a testing class is constructed at the end and the subsets from the pool are assigned.
# note the length of result_list is 4 as there were 4 processes
# you can merge these into a single list if that's what you need
anObjetct = Testing(None, None)
anObjetct.subsets = result_list
```

Comment: I've just realised that you probably don't want to split `data`. Instead, send a copy of the full size matrix to each mutiprocess for the process to create subsets from it.